# Will a spike protector work in reverse?

Tags: appliances

Will a spike protector work in reverse?  Protect the *circuit* from an *appliance*?

My attic lights' blubs blow 10x faster than any other bulbs in the house.  I think it's because everything in the attic is on the same circuit, including these lights and an old crappy refrigerator, which turns itself on and off again every 15 minutes or so.  I figure it is spiking the line every time it turns off.

I can't spike protect the lights (without knocking holes in the walls) but I can easily insert a spike protector between the circuit and the fridge.  Would that do the trick?  Since it's just a glorified capacitor in series?

Comment: What kind of bulbs are you using? Do they dim or flash when the fridge kicks on? Do you have a multimeter to take min & max voltage readings from an outlet on that circuit?

Comment: Is the attic on a subpanel?

Comment: Not on a subpanel.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not really a glorified capacitor, but yes, it will work both ways. Of course, so would recycling the crappy fridge and getting one that isn't turning on every 15 minutes and doesn't make a huge spike when it does turn on. That can't be helping your power bill much.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea whether surge protectors function "in reverse", but I doubt it would make much difference in your situation anyway, for the following reasons:

- Surge suppressors are *not* just capacitors, they typically have a clamping voltage above which the suppressor will cut off power. The clamping voltage may be 2 or 3 times the regular voltage (i.e. much higher). Below that voltage the suppressor has no effect. So any minor voltage fluctuations in your house are unlikely to be corrected by the surge suppressor.
- I would be surprised if the fridge were causing a voltage spike in the first place. Many fridges will cause a small *drop* when the compressor starts, but I can't see how that would affect an incandescent light bulb. Maybe the voltage on that circuit is just too high to begin with? Or there are other factors (heat, vibration) that are causing the bulbs to fail? Or if you have non-dimable fluorescent or LED lights, the momentary voltage dip may be causing excess wear on the bulbs.

I would recommend replacing the bulbs with dimmable LEDs (which will save you money on electricity as well as having an extremely long life). You could also look into "rough service" light bulbs, which are rated for higher voltage and a tougher filament.

(Side note: an old fridge can be a huge energy hog. You might consider replacing it anyway, which will save you money on your electric bill.)

Comment: The expensive LED's might be damaged by whatever is wrong with this circuit.  Replace the fridge first!

Comment: @Bryce: I'm not convinced the bulb problem is related to the fridge, and also I can't see how the fridge could cause a voltage surge. Dimmable LEDs are very good about compensating for unusual incoming voltages, since they convert triac dimmer waveforms into something usable by the DC diodes. (Non-dimmable LEDs might be a little more fragile in that respect.) Also, excellent LEDs can now be had for well under $10 in my area, which makes them a bargain in my mind.

Comment: I'm sure the fridge IS a problem, why not eliminate it first.

Comment: In fact, many utility companies will pay you to take an old fridge or freezer out of operation and let them recycle it safely, precisely because so many of them draw so much power. (And contain refrigerants which are damaging to the ozone layer if leaked.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Every time the refridgerator pump stopped, flatscreen tv turned black, and lifetime for old wolfram light bulbs was very short. I put a resistor and a capacitor in series across the ac line by the fridge. I used a 47 ohm 150 w resistor and a 3,3 uF capacitor.