# Reverse surge protection

Tags: electrical, surge-suppression, power-supply

This is somewhat related to the question I found here:
[Will a spike protector work in reverse?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/40581/will-a-spike-protector-work-in-reverse?newreg=99c467e97757434f82fac873efba4a0e)

I have a trusty old 3D printer running on the same power strip as my two computers including a screen.

Whenever I turned on the printer, my screen would turn off for a short moment before turning back on.

A few weeks later my screen would turn off and on continously, and when checking the connections of the screen I realized sparks were flying between the screens back plate and the display cable. The screen's warranty had of course ended a few months ago and I had to replace it in fear of fire hazard.

With my new screen, on the first time I turned the printer on, it too started turning off and on continously, even after unplugging the printer. I suspcted the worst, only now all puzzle pieces falling together. What if the printer produces a power surge when turned on and fried both my screens? Fortunately after plugging my screen into a different strip (and thus also performing a hard power reset on the screen) the problem seems to have subsided.

Now for my actual question, is there a way I can protect my devices from the 3D printer? Could I use a power surge protector between the printer and the power strip? Or plug in the power strip into a power surge protector and then into another power strip with the  printer attached to it as well?

Comment: Could be your display cable is wonky/bad or screens are defective.  Would try to put the 3D printer on another house circuit with a different breaker.  Sparks at a connection is a sign of a bad connection, not a power surge.

Comment: I doubt a surge. More likely is a *drop* in voltage when the 3D printer starts up. Put it on a different circuit.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, this is not the millisecond sort of surge that surge protectors are designed to work with.

This is a power loss problem.  I suspect a problem in the power strip or the receptacle is causing a high resistance connection.  I would watch out for any plug connections getting warm, as that is serious and could start a fire.

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck on my phone that day.